# prevent layout breaking in zoom-in/zoom-out of the browser - not the usual div thing

Tags: css, button, css-float, html, zooming

So I did notice that zoom related layout problems are commonly being dealt with, but I couldn't find an answer to my case - I wrote [a WEB calc](http://yovelzack.fav.cc/), and the buttons just **slide out of place** when zooming in and out, in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE. What is the way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of searchers, my solutions was to use a table to make the calculator eventually. I know using tables for layout is considered a bad practice, but considering a calculator shape is not supposed to adjust to new contents or to the size of the end-user's screen (at least in my case) it seemed to be the best implementation. It was the only way to avoid losing the layout shape in zoom-in zoom-out, which is kind of what div's are all about.

Answer (score 0):

**Give `width:220px` to your #main div**

If you closely look at your CSS you will see that the buttons together(5 in a line) actually have more width than the Main div while resizing. Increasing the width to `220px` solves that problem. Another solution could be to give max-width and max-height to all elements, another can be to properly layout your elements and don't just rely on the browser's positioning. Doing the latter is an trivial task.

Comment: So, can you elaborate a bit about the latter?

Comment: Contain your buttons in a div with white-space:pre property.

Comment: Well, that broke my layout completely. Can you make a jsFiddle to better explain what you mean?

Comment: I think the easiest would be to use width:200px;

Comment: It does not solve the problem, unless I just don't get what your saying. I wish you'd create a jsFiddle to show me what you mean.